# How to brute force ARJ password

Tags: archive

The other day I found a 3,5" floppy in my basement. It's one of my backup floppies I used in 1995 and it has several ARJ archives on it.
I still have a floppy drive and yes, it is still readable  :-)

The thing is that the archives are password protected.
Can anyone name a password cracker for arj archives that runs on linux?

Comment: If you don't find one for Linux, anything that works for DOS will work with dosemu.

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days of searching and finally asking here, I just came across this: http://www.password-crackers.com/en/category_100/program_16.html

It's only listed as being for Windows, but has a 32 bit ELF executable as well.

I successfully unarchived a MS-Word file from 1989-07-25, must have been Word 3 or Word 4 at that time... OMG, digital archeology!

History of Microsoft Word https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwXkzH_Rf3k

Comment: the archive from  their file has a password itself.